# trouble with appending unicode object to list

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, unicode, python-2.x

I am tyring to import from this xml feed http://www.lnv.fr/xml/ajaccio/calendrier.xml
I have having some trouble because some of the data I want to extract has French accent marks.

```
url = 'http://www.lnv.fr/xml/ajaccio/calendrier.xml'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
matches = soup.findAll('match')
```

When I do this

```
for match in matches:
    print match.equipedomicile.string
```

It prints them out as they should there is no problem with a team with accent marks like **Sète** for example.

But when I do this

```
def GetGames():
homeTeamList = []    
for match in matches:
    homeTeam = unicode(match.equipedomicile.text)        
    homeTeamList.append(homeTeam)
return homeTeamList
```

and call the function the list teams with accent marks don't come out right.  ie **Sète**
now becomes **u'S\xe8te'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're getting is a `repr` version of the unicode string, use `print` on individual elements of the list and you'll get the correct output.

```
>>> a = [u'S\xe8te']
>>> a
[u'S\xe8te']
>>> print a[0]
Sète
```